# Blackberry Simulator OS 7 Browser distortion

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am testing our web app for various mobile devices. In this case, I’m running a Blackberry simulator that simulates a Blackberry Bold 9900 running Blackberry OS 7. There is nothing out of the ordinary in my pages. The first page is not particularly special, it is Html, jquery, and jquerymobile. However, the Blackberry simulator's browser shows my page like a 1970s  color TV that needs its rabbit ears adjusted.

I don't have access to a real blackberry at the moment, but I've been told that our pages don't show this distortion on real hardware.

Are there any workarounds to get the simulator to better reflect that real hardware? 
Is there something in my Html that is messing up the presentation on the simulator? If I don't use jquerymobile, it looks fine (for whatever that is worth).

I tried the same experiment with the jquerymobile demo site.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/intro/ - shows the same colorful mess as my app. See captured image below. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-demo-page-causes-blackberry-7-1-simulator-browser-to-crash has an interesting comment from a Blackberry employee:

> The page does load, but not without some very major rendering
>   artifacts (there appears to be a colourful static/noise overlay on top
>   of the content.)

The simulator came from the [Blackberry site](http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/resources/simulators.html).

---   Update

Blackberry device simulators can be downloaded from http://us.blackberry.com/sites/developers/resources/simulators.html
You can download simulators for a specific device and OS version. It seems that some of the simulators are buggy and don’t support jQueryMobile. However, I’ve found that the Blackberry 9790 for Blackberry OS 7 works well so far. This is 7.0.0.592 (9790).

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, but only with the 9900 v7.1 simulator. v7.0 seems to work "ok". Were you able to figure anything else out around this?

Answer (score 1):

I tracked this problem down to CSS, and more specifically the following tags:

```
   -webkit-perspective:
   -webkit-transform:
```

when commenting these out everything was fine.

**Update**: It seems like upgrading the graphics driver may solve this problem (it didn't work for me):
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Blackberry-7-emulators-bug/td-p/1409051

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error with the program itself, not your HTML.  If your code works fine on the real thing but not on the simulator, then it's probably the simulator.